# How to do abstractization to some classes of the OpenCV library

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a class that trains and tests a NormalBayesClassifier based on the Bag of Words from OpenCV. Now I want to compare it with a SVM multi-class classifier based on the same BOW. My idea is not to rewrite the same class and change only the classifier to SVM instead of NormalBayes. The OpenCV classifiers do not have an interface that will help me in this purpose, so I have thought of creating one, myself. But how to do this?

I thought of something like this:

```
// my interface
class IClassifierPtr
{
public:
    virtual void train(const cv::Mat& trainDataIn, const cv::Mat& labelsIn) = 0;
    virtual double predict(const cv::Mat& testDataIn, cv::Mat* groundTruthIn) = 0;
};

//////////////////////////////

// my normal bayes classifier
class MyNormalBayesClassifier : public IClassifierPtr
{
private:
    cv::Ptr< cv::NormalBayesClassifier > m_classifier;

public:
    void train(const cv::Mat& trainDataIn, const cv::Mat& labelsIn);
    double predict(const cv::Mat& testDataIn, cv::Mat* groundTruthIn);
};

//////////////////////////////

// my svm classifier
class MySVMClassifier : public IClassifierPtr
{
private:
    cv::Ptr< cv::SVM > m_classifier;

public:
    void train(const cv::Mat& trainDataIn, const cv::Mat& labelsIn);
    double predict(const cv::Mat& testDataIn, cv::Mat* groundTruthIn);
};
```

each one with its specific implementation. And just change the classifier in my training/testing class with the interface and based on an input flag to use the wanted classifier. What do you think, is this the way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will be much easier in opencv3, where they all inherit from a proper StatModel version(including train()/predict()).

but, if you find, that you got *exactly the same code* in your methods, maybe you can get away with templates:

(warning: i haven't tried, no 2.4 on current machine, the train()/predict() impl might get pesky)

```
template < typename Classifier >
class MyClassifier : public IClassifierPtr
{
private:
    cv::Ptr< Classifier > m_classifier;

public:
    MyClassifier(Ptr<Classifier> cl)
       :  m_classifier(cl)
    {}

    void train(const cv::Mat& trainDataIn, const cv::Mat& labelsIn);
    double predict(const cv::Mat& testDataIn, cv::Mat* groundTruthIn);
};


...
// later:

MyClassifier<cv::NormalBayesClassifier> bayes( new cv::NormalBayesClassifier(... specific params...) );
MyClassifier<cv::SVM>                   svm( new cv::SVM(... specific params...) );
```

Comment: Thanks, it is also in 2.4.9, so I'll try to use it.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to call the `SVM::train_auto` from `StatModel`?

Comment: not really. also train_auto() only does a lot of regular train() / predict() passes on a parameter grid. you can maybe write something similar

Comment: I think I am going to make a template. I'll post it as answer for reviews when it is finished.

Comment: yes, I just did not figure out that StatModel is the parent of all the classifiers, even if I knew about it...

Comment: :( I do not get it why `‘class CvStatModel’ has no member named ‘train’` in 2.4.9 ... Any suggestions? It appears in the docs.

Comment: Uh: `In this declaration, some methods are commented off. These are methods for which there is no unified API (with the exception of the default constructor). However, there are many similarities in the syntax and semantics that are briefly described below in this section, as if they are part of the base class.`

Comment: tbh, the 2.4 ml module is a horrible mess ;( no, statmodel has neither train() nor predict(), so having that as a base-class is a bit pointless. things *will* get better in 3.0 !

Comment: I have seen that 3 is better in this purpose. And that the train and predict are commented "to be included in future" in the 2.4.X...

Comment: anyway, do you know how long is going to take the work on the OpenCV's forum?

Comment: ^^ no idea, not involved there, sorry ;(